# How can we combine multiple enternal .js file and .css file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, codeigniter

I have created a website in codeigniter. Now, I have checking my website performance through gtmetrix. It show low score of YSlow due to cause of multiple .js and .css file. Now I want to combine .js file into single file and single file for .css. So, How can I do this ?Please hel p me. Here's  my external css file and .js file.

css file

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resources/plugins/flexslider/flexslider.css" />    
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resources/css/cubeportfolio.min.css" />
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resources/css/index.css" />
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resources/css/index2.css" />
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resources/skins/default.css" />
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resources/css/jquery-ui.css" /> 
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resources/css/ui.theme.css"/>
```

js file

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resources/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resources/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resources/js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resources/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resources/plugins/flexslider/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resources/plugins/flexslider/flexslider.config.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resources/js/custom.js"></script>
```

Comment: use https://gruntjs.com/ or do it manualy create a main file and copy each files in the main file

Comment: Try with `Elixir` or `Mix` with CodeIgniter.(Both of them are used in Laravel).